# Why does this image rendering benchmark crash on IOS but not in the simulator?

Tags: codenameone

I tried to get a grasp of image rendering performance and created some code which draws full screen images using mutable images and PNGs.

The code runs fine in the simulator but on an iPhone SE it crashes after 50 seconds or short before a million images.

Is it a bug or is there another explanation since it doesn't crash in the simulator and I cannot see a memory leak in jvisualvm?

Here is the code:

```
public class FormMeasureImage extends Form implements Painter {
    abstract class Wallpaper implements Painter {
        private Component componentParent;

        public Wallpaper(Component aComponentParent) {
            componentParent = aComponentParent;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics aGraphics, Rectangle aRectangle) {
            aGraphics.drawImage(
                    getImage(new Dimension(componentParent.getWidth(), componentParent.getHeight())),
                    0,
                    0);
        }

        public abstract Image getImage(Dimension aDimension);
    }

    class WallpaperTiledIcons extends Wallpaper {
        private Image image;
        private Dimension dimension;

        public WallpaperTiledIcons(Component aComponentParent) {
            super(aComponentParent);
        }

        public Image getImage(Dimension aDimension) {
            if ((null == image || !dimension.equals(aDimension)) && null != aDimension) {
                dimension = new Dimension(aDimension);
                Label labelPattern = new Label("1234567890");
                Style styleLabelPattern = labelPattern.getAllStyles();
                styleLabelPattern.setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
                styleLabelPattern.setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
//              byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
//              Arrays.fill(bytes, Style.UNIT_TYPE_PIXELS);
//              styleLabelPattern.setPaddingUnit(bytes);
                styleLabelPattern.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 1);
                Dimension preferredSizeLabelPattern = labelPattern.getPreferredSize();
                labelPattern.setSize(preferredSizeLabelPattern);
                Image imagePattern = Image.createImage(
                        preferredSizeLabelPattern.getWidth(),
                        preferredSizeLabelPattern.getHeight(),
                        0x00000000);
                Graphics graphicsImagePattern = imagePattern.getGraphics();
                graphicsImagePattern.setAlpha(255);
                labelPattern.paint(graphicsImagePattern);
                image = Image.createImage(
                        aDimension.getWidth(),
                        aDimension.getHeight(),
                        0xff606060);
                Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();
                if (graphics.isAntiAliasingSupported()) {
                    graphics.setAntiAliased(true);
                }
                int canvasWidth = preferredSizeLabelPattern.getWidth(), canvasHeight = preferredSizeLabelPattern.getHeight();
                int[] clip = graphics.getClip();
                Rectangle rectangleClip = new Rectangle(clip[0], clip[1], clip[2], clip[3]);
                int columns = (rectangleClip.getX() + rectangleClip.getWidth()) / canvasWidth + 1;
                int rows = (rectangleClip.getY() + rectangleClip.getHeight()) / canvasHeight + 1;
                for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                    for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
                        int x = canvasWidth * column;
                        int y = canvasHeight * row;
                        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
                        if (!rectangleClip.intersects(rectangle)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        graphics.drawImage(imagePattern, x, y);
                    }
                }
            }
            return image;
        }
    }

    abstract class Stage {
        long millisTotal;
        long tally;
        TextArea textArea;

        public Stage(String aName) {
            textArea = new TextArea();
            textArea.setEditable(false);
            getContentPane().add(textArea);
            stages.add(this);
        }

        abstract void perform();
        abstract boolean isPainted();
    }

    private Wallpaper wallpaper;
    private List<Stage> stages = new ArrayList<>();
    private Iterator<Stage> iteratorStages;
    private Image imageEncoded;

    public FormMeasureImage() {
        super("FormMeasureImage", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setScrollableX(false);
        setScrollableY(true);
        Style styleForm = getAllStyles();
        styleForm.setBgTransparency(255);
        styleForm.setBgPainter(this);
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setText("Measuring image throughput.");
        add(textArea);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics aGraphics, Rectangle aRectangle) {
        if (null == iteratorStages) {
            new Stage("create") {
                void perform() {
                    long millisBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    wallpaper = new WallpaperTiledIcons(FormMeasureImage.this);
                    wallpaper.getImage(aRectangle.getSize());
                    millisTotal += System.currentTimeMillis() - millisBefore;
                    tally++;
                    textArea.setText("create: " + millisTotal + " / " + tally);
                }

                boolean isPainted() {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            new Stage("mutable") {
                void perform() {
                    long millisBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
                        wallpaper.paint(aGraphics, aRectangle);
                        tally++;
                    }
                    millisTotal += System.currentTimeMillis() - millisBefore;
                    textArea.setText("mutable: " + millisTotal + " / " + tally);
                }

                boolean isPainted() {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            new Stage("encoding") {
                void perform() {
                    long millisBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    try {
                        millisBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        ImageIO.getImageIO().save(wallpaper.getImage(null), byteArrayOutputStream, ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG, 1);
                        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                        imageEncoded = Image.createImage(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
                        tally++;
                        millisTotal += System.currentTimeMillis() - millisBefore;
                        textArea.setText("encoding: " + millisTotal + " / " + tally);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
                    }
                    millisTotal += System.currentTimeMillis() - millisBefore;
                    tally++;
                    textArea.setText("encoding: " + millisTotal + " / " + tally);
                }

                boolean isPainted() {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            new Stage("encoded") {
                void perform() {
                    long millisBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
                        aGraphics.drawImage(
                                imageEncoded,
                                0,
                                0);
                        tally++;
                    }
                    millisTotal += System.currentTimeMillis() - millisBefore;
                    textArea.setText("encoded: " + millisTotal + " / " + tally);
                }

                boolean isPainted() {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            iteratorStages = stages.iterator();
        }
        while (!perform().isPainted()) {;}
    }

    private Stage perform() {
        if (!iteratorStages.hasNext()) {
            iteratorStages = stages.iterator();
        }
        Stage stage = iteratorStages.next();
        stage.perform();
        return stage;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a bit too much code here. I suggest elimination until you narrow down the problematic portion and then I might be able to guess.

Comment: There is not too much code once you know that the inner classes `Wallpaper` and `WallpaperTiledIcons` just create background mutable images which then are painted repeatedly measuring the time it takes to do so.

Comment: On an iPad Air 2 the code crashes much faster than on an iPhone SE.

Comment: See https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2133

Comment: I narrowed it down to decoding PNG images.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the test case included an EDT violation of decoding off the EDT. This can work for some cases but because of the heavy usage it crashes.

Making UI code threadsafe is a difficult task which is doubly so cross platforms.

Comment: The code here has no EDT issues. I have corrected the proof code in issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2133 derived from this - it still crashes.

Comment: You still call `threadEncodingLoop.start()` the sample is too big so I might be missing something

Comment: Yes, and the thread loops and does lots of decodings (and optionally lots of encodings,too). It shouldn't be required that images are decided in the EDT, right? Anyway I extracted the code here from another example which ran on EDT only and crashed the same

Comment: Nope. All methods must be invoked on the EDT unless explicitly stated otherwise. If you have a smaller example I can take a look but it won't be anytime soon as we are almost at a code freeze.

Comment: I replaced the code in [#2133](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2133) which now fully runs within the EDT. It still crashes.

Comment: I've reopened the issue, I would suggest debugging this in xcode if you have access to a Mac and seeing why this crashes